# My javascript regex is unreliable

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the regex I'm using

```
.match(/\[(.*)\]\s*([^\s]+)\s*([^\s]+)\s*(.*)/)
```

and it fails to capture the timestamp properly when there is another close square bracket

```
[2016-01-22 22:14:58,098] WARN  service.catalog.MediaController  - foo1 foo foo foo foo foo
[2016-01-22 22:14:58,235] WARN  service.catalog.MediaController  - foo2 foo foo foo foo foo]; sdfd sf sd
[2016-01-22 22:14:58,240] INFO  service.catalog.RestAPIController  - foo3 foo foo foo] foo foo
[2016-01-22 22:14:58,259] INFO  service.catalog.DynamicRoutingController  - foo4 foo foo foo foo foo
[2016-01-22 22:14:58,457] ERROR service.catalog.BaseController  - foo5 foo foo foo foo foo
```

Comment: Oh, it cannot be reliable because it contains `.*` and `[^\s]+`. Consider something more restrictive, like `\w+` and `\d+`.

Comment: `.*` is greedy and will match *as much* as possible. `.*?` is lazy and will match as *little* as possible. Consider using `\[([^\]]+)\]` meaning `[ followed by any character that isn't ] matched 1 to infinity times followed by ]`

Comment: I got it working but it's ugly - .match(/\[(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)\]\s*([^\s]+)\s*([^\s]+)\s*(.*)/);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\[(.*?)\]
```

[Demo - RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/oZ2cQ6/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try to make your regex more restrictive by matching the pattern more closely.

So for example, for the timestamp in the beginning use something like this:

```
\[\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d\]
```

This way you will make sure there are no false positive matches

Comment: Yup, that's what I did as I posted about.

Comment: Must have been at about the same time. If it helps, please upvote and accept.

Comment: According www.rubular.com, the expression `/[`and `/]`is not correct.

Comment: @reporter: my bad, slashes in the wrong direction. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp seems to have a straight forward layout, why not capture that explicitly:

```
var regex = /\[\d{2,4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:,|.)\d+\]/;
'[2016-01-22 22:14:58,235] WARN  service.catalog.MediaController  - foo2 foo foo foo foo foo]; sdfd sf sd'.match(regex) // -> ["[2016-01-22 22:14:58,235]"]
```

I've included for the year to have 2 instead of 4 digits and your milliseconds being separated by , or .

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear what you want to achive. My idea is `\d{1,4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{1,3}`. If you want do capture the brackets either, add `\[` and `\]` to the expression.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
/\[[\d-\s:,]+]/gm
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA0bU7/1)

PD: Your option is not bad idea, is the most specific that can be, and that´s good: [(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)]